# What's the difference between Arc<Mutex<_>> and std::sync::atomic::Atomic_?

Tags: rust

I have no experience using Atomic_, below is how I used to share states.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let shared_value = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let mut handles = vec![];
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let copy_ref = shared_value.clone();
        let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut guard = copy_ref.lock().unwrap();
            *guard += 1;
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.await.unwrap();
    }

    println!("{}", *shared_value.lock().unwrap());
}
```

I am looking for:

1. The equivalent operation using atomic.
2. Their potential difference in behavior.

Comment: `Arc` and atomics have no overlap (except that `Arc` is implemented with atomics). `Mutex` and atomics do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The equivalent operation using atomic.

[`fetch_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI32.html#method.fetch_add) and [`load`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI32.html#method.load)

> Their potential difference in behavior.

Atomics only have pretty trivial state, and unless you rebuild a mutex out of atomics they only guarantee coherence of a single operation. In order to have multi-operation coherence on atomics you need to use something like [`fetch_update`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI32.html#method.fetch_update) (or the underlying [`compare_exchange`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI32.html#method.compare_exchange)) and potentially perform the operation multiple times before it can finally be applied. Notably, atomics are sensible to [the ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem).

On the other hand, atomics tend to be a lot cheaper, and somewhat less sensible to contention (especially when using native atomic operations).